# mathematical if else statement

Tags: logic

What would be the best way of writing the following if else statement:

```
if((t + n) > 25) then
    c = (t + n) - 25
else
    c = (t + n)
endif
```

or the best way of writing the following if elseif statement:

```
if((t + n) > 25) then
    c = (t + n) - 25
elseif((t + n) <= 25) then
    c = (t + n)
endif
```

*Edit: Fixed typo in the if line changing 15 to 25*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$c=\begin{cases}t+n-25 & t+n>25\\t+n & t+n\le 25\end{cases}$$
or
$$c=\begin{cases}t+n-25 & t+n>25\\t+n & \text{ otherwise }\end{cases}$$

The (revised) second statement has a redundant test, since if the first if is "no" then the second "if" is automatically "yes.  This may be written as

$$c=\begin{cases}t+n-25 & t+n>25\\t+n & \text{ otherwise }\end{cases}$$

A true 3-way situation may be written as
$$c=\begin{cases}t+n-25 & t+n\le 15\\t+n & 15<t+n\le 25\\ t+n-3 & 25<t+n\end{cases}$$

Note: This solution assumes that these statements execute in order.  If it is possible for the value of $t+n$ to change between the execution of the "if" part and the "elseif" part, then all bets are off.  No mathematical notation that I know of can model this behavior.

Comment: I am pretty sure $\{x > 15\} \cup \{x\leq 25\} = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Actually, the second statement is equivalent to the first. Note that if you are in the "elseif" case, then already you must have $(t+n)\le 15$, so certainly $(t+n) \le 25$.

Comment: Sorry the 15 was ment to be 25 in both the if statements.

Comment: My comment still holds. They are equivalent.